# Number Format Exception while Exporting data from Hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am planning to export a table by mentioning `starttime` and `endtime` in hbase. Since I am new to this I assumed that the start time and end time is the timestamp which is inserted along with the rows.

My table consists of:

> ```
> ROW        COLUMN+CELL
>  1         column=d:A, timestamp=1439284609013, value=HHHH
>  1         column=d:B, timestamp=1439284620216, value=HHHH111
>  2         column=d:A, timestamp=1439284637133, value=HHHH
>  2         column=d:B, timestamp=1439284641872, value=HHHH111
>  3         column=d:A, timestamp=1439284646830, value=HHHH
>  3         column=d:B, timestamp=1439284651527, value=HHHH111
>  3         column=d:C, timestamp=1439284665492, value=HHHH
> ```

I have executed:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export emp1 ~/KT/bkp 1439284609013 1439284641872
```

I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1439284609013"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export.getConfiguredScanForJob(Export.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export.createSubmittableJob(Export.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export.main(Export.java:201)
```

Help me what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entered only the start time and end time. Export is expecting versions before start and end time. So finally I entered the version number it worked.

```
./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export emp1 ~/KT/bkp 2147483647 1439284609013 1439284646830
```

Answer (score 4):

The exact cause of the exception is, that the number `1439284609013` is too big to fit into `Integer`.

However, the actual issue lies elsewhere. I have looked at the source code, your parameters seem to be wrong:

```
emp1 ~/KT/bkp 1439284609013 1439284641872
```

You have given a `String`, another `String` and two `Long`s, these are the

- `args[0]`: `tableName`
- `args[1]`: `outputDir`
- `args[2]`: `startTime`
- `args[3]`: `endTime`

the problem is, that you are missing an argument: `args[2]` should be an `Integer`,`startTime` should become `args[3]` and `endTime` should become
`args[4]`.

In the source, that expected third, `Integer` argument is called `versions`, however I don't exactly know what that means.

---

#### Official documentation

Going through the source is one thing, but the [official docs](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_export) also give the syntax of `Export` the following:

> `$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]]`
>
> By default, the Export tool only exports the newest version of a given cell, regardless of the number of versions stored. To export more than one version, replace `<versions>` with the desired number of versions.

---

#### Wrapping it up

To achive what you wanted originally, just simple add `1` as the third argument:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export emp1 ~/KT/bkp 1 1439284609013 1439284641872
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. See I am trying to do this activity by entering the command in console....so how can i convert it to long ?

Answer (score 3):

Timestamps are usually associated to Long types, that have 64 bits

Integers have 32 bits and the range is only -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 in Java